# Reset each element on draggable div

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable, each

I have a list of categories each containing a list of contacts. Contacts dive contains user details which is shown in a table, with input elements. Contacts div is made draggable, and category div made droppable . When i move the contact from one category to another i want to rename input fields of the contact div being dragged. I tried the code below but it does not work:

```
$(function() {
        $(".contact_draggable").draggable({cursor: "crosshair", snap: ".category_snap_to_target", revert: "invalid"});
        $(".category_snap_to_target").droppable({ 
            accept: ".contact_draggable",  
            drop: function(event, ui){
                $.each($( ui.input ), function() {
                    $(this).attr("name", "new_name");
                });
                return true;
            }
        });
 });
```

I think the problem lies at the $.each part. I tried $.each($( ui ).find("input"), function() { as well by did not work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end this worked...

```
$.each($( ui.draggable ).find("input"), function() {
```